# Show Indeterminate progress bar in react native IOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, progress-bar

I want to show a progress **bar** in indeterminate state for my react native app for IOS. I specifically need the progress bar, not the spinning circle.

React native has `ProgressViewIOS` control. However, it doesn't support indeterminate state.

Is there any way to achieve I want?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [react-native-progress](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress) that will let you show a progress bar of this type.